# OpenCv: Filling in characters

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I have used adaptive thresholding on an image to turn it from

[image]
to this

[image]

with `adaptiveThreshold(src, src, 255, ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, THRESH_BINARY, 11, 2);`

Is there a way I could smooth out the characters, specifically with OCR in mind? Or am I better to adjust my adaptive threshold params?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the assumption of clear text on a solid background, I found [Otsu's binarization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otsu%27s_method) very good.

Here's some C++ Code.

```
cvtColor(src, src, COLOR_RGB2GRAY); //Make grayscale
threshold(src, src, 0, 255, THRESH_BINARY+THRESH_OTSU);
```

Answer (score 2):

If the letter is always with specific colour you can use colour based segmentation,

- [Convert source to hsv](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#cvtcolor) colour space.
- Perform [inRange()](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#inrange) between lower and upper threshold for the particular colour.

For the above image you culd use some thing like

```
 Mat src=imread("l.jpg",1);
 Mat hsv,thr;
 cvtColor(src,hsv,CV_BGR2HSV);
 inRange(hsv,Scalar(76,84,86),Scalar(135,255,255),thr);
 imshow("thr",thr);
```

See the result,

[image]

Comment: Interesting idea. I don't know the colour ahead of time, but I could can assume a difference in contrast... usually, white, black or solid coloured text on a white, black or solid coloured background. Any ideas to take advantage of that?

Comment: Oooo Otsu's binarization looks promising.

Comment: Normally contrast, lightness change doesn’t affect hsv-color space, but you should know about the color.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [morphological operations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_morphology). Especially dilation followed by erosion.